# Notification at specific time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have a notification at a specific time, see my code:

```
//Create alarm manager
 AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

 //Create pending intent & register it to your alarm notifier class
 Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver_maandag_1e.class);
 intent0.putExtra("uur", "1e"); 
 PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent0, 0);

 //set timer you want alarm to work (here I have set it to 8.30)
 Calendar timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
 timeOff9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
 timeOff9.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
 timeOff9.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

 //set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
 alarmMgr0.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff9.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent0);
```

This works perfect except one thing.

The notification is set for 8:30 with an alarm manager
If I launch the app after 8:30, 9:00 for example, the notification still shows..

Is there a possibility that the alarm goes off at 8:30 but not later?

**Edit**

For anyone having the same problem, here is the solution:

Put this in your broadcastreceiver:

```
long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

Calendar timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
timeOff9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
timeOff9.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
timeOff9.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long limit_time = timeOff9.getTimeInMillis();

if (current_time > limit_time) {
    //nothing
} else {
    //show notification
}
```

Comment: Check the current time and alarm time in broadcast receiver class. I that class you may decide where notification should show or not.

Comment: Do you know how I can compare current time to 8:30? Because I guess you mean something like: if (current time == 8:30) @Ilango

Comment: You know your alarm time and current time by System.currentTimeMillis() and check with this time.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this method of Alarm Manager:

```
public void setExact (int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

But it requiers API level 19.