# Android: status bar notifications in specific time

Tags: android, time, notifications

I have app which in specific time start notification in status bar.But when that time elapsed, every time when I launch the app he start the notification again.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

Activity: MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //notifications with solve problem

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30 );
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


        calendar.getTimeInMillis();


        long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();



        long limit_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        if (current_time > limit_time) {
            //nothing
        } else {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);


            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }

        }

    }
```

Activity: MyReceiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);

  }
}
```

Activity: MyAlarmService

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service{

     private NotificationManager mManager;

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
   {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
   }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
  }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
 {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Run this app", System.currentTimeMillis() );
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "Horoscope", "Run this app", pendingNotificationIntent);

    mManager.notify(0, notification);
 }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy()
  {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onDestroy();
  }

}
```

I solve the problem with this post - [Notification at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744654/android-notification-at-specific-time)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), SYNC_REPEAT_MILLSECONDS, pendingIntent);
```

instead of

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```